# Getting Invalid sender action data when trying to mark_seen instagram direct message

Tags: instagram, messenger

{{
"recipient": {
"id": "5144867005573717"
},
"sender_action": "mark_seen"
}}

Api Response:

{{
"error": {
"message": "(#100) Invalid sender action data",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"error_subcode": 2534019,
"fbtrace_id": "Aq5V2HVmpQRbs1uBrxvq6_D"
}
}}

The same method works for messenger, it works good for sending text media messages but for sender actions it doesn't work

Does messenger api sender actions supports instgram messeging as well?

Comment: Curious if you ever found out the answer to this question. Facing same issue.